# Как в react native посмотреть статистику использования других приложений?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Есть ли возможность в react native посмотреть статистику использования других приложений(и на ios и на android)? Необходимо получить информацию о времени использования приложений и как часто они запускаются.

Comment: Для андроида попробуйте вот это попробовать: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html Однако вряд ли вы сумеете найти способ (тем более кроссплатформенный) для сбора такой информации без запроса у юзера разных разрешений (которые ему надо вручную в настройках искать). Эта информация - очень приватная, т.к. позволяет легко идентифицировать юзера. Засим доступ к ней очень ограничен. На этом (в т.ч.) заработывают корпорации зла и делиться этим с обычными людьми они не будут.